# error of assigning primary key of 0

Tags: delphi, records

The aim of the error filled code is to assign the same primary key to two records, each belonging to a different file (member and loan file)  . Below is the code used to assign the primary key to the member file   .

```
AssignFile(MemberDetailsFile, 'MemberDetails.dat');
Reset(MemberDetailsFile);
if FileSize(MemberDetailsFile) = 0 then
  MemberRecords.UniqueId := 1
  { if there are no records in the file then UID will be 1 }
else
begin
  while not eof(MemberDetailsFile) do
  begin
    read(MemberDetailsFile, MemberRecords);
  end;
  ID := MemberRecords.UniqueId + 1;
end;
{ add 1 to the last Unique ID given to generate the new UID- if there are
records in the file }
end;
```

And this code calls the above procedure and takes the value assigned to ID, and assigns the same value to the loan record primary key  .

```
btnSave.Enabled := false;
CreateUniqueID(MemberRecords.UniqueId);
lblUID.Caption := IntToStr(MemberRecords.UniqueId);
AssignFile(LoanFile, 'LoanFile.dat');
Reset(MemberFile);
Reset(LoanFile);
SaveDetails;
MemberRecords.MemberFine := 0;
write(MemberDetailsFile, MemberRecords);
LoanRecords.LoanUniqueId := MemberRecords.UniqueId;
{ Loan ID will be equal to Member ID }
LoanRecords.MemberUniqueID := MemberRecords.UniqueId;
LoanRecords.MemberName := MemberRecords.MemberName;
LoanRecords.MemberSecondName := MemberRecords.MemberSecondName;
{ write to file and record }
write(LoanFile, LoanRecords);
CloseFile(MemberDetailsFile);
CloseFile(LoanFile);
```

The errors are that only one records saves to the member file, so it keeps overwriting the existing one record. At times it'll say it doen't exist. The loan ID also works for a little while and then assigns its primary key to 0? Is it just a rewrite/reset error?

Comment: Just curious, why not use an actual database?

Comment: @GolezTrol we just got taught how to use files in delphi

Answer (score 0):

If the file already exists, you must use `Reset` rather than `Rewrite`.

`Rewrite` recreates the file and thus wipes any existing file with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that ReWrite will overwrite the contents of the file. You should use Reset when opening a file for reading and writing. You can get a bit smarter on the getting of your unique id too. You could just use the file size to see how many records you have in the file. Something like this:

```
AssignFile(MemberDetailsFile, 'MemberDetails.dat');
Reset(MemberDetailsFile);
MemberRecords.UniqueId := FileSize(MemberDetailsFile) + 1;
```

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I realised that, obvious mistake. I was initially planning on the filesize method since i'm quite familliar with it but my tutor told me it would make deleting records harder so had to come up with a new method

Comment: You could use seek to jump to the last record.

Comment: @user1008646 Again rejected by the tutor so just sticking to improving what i have

Comment: I've changed the code so it has reset but now i have a problem with the loan id! It sets the correct value on the code above but when i access it outside of the displayed code, it's been assigned the value 0? –

Comment: @GrayMatter any idea on the 0 value?

Comment: @user129092: If everything we might answer is "rejected by your tutor", then perhaps you should **ask your tutor** to explain instead of asking us. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite I did and we sat there and tried to figure it out and then i got no feedback after the break so I came here as a last resort . Please try to bear in mind that as a student I may not have a complete understanding and have I have literally sat for hours debugging the code and trying to work out what is wrong before asking.